# Why is my strip() function is not working after input()?

Tags: python

I'm trying to strip some whitespace out of some user input and it's not working.

I've tried doing this:

```
image_id = input("Enter an AMI ID: ")
image_id = image_id.strip(' ')
print(f"The AMI ID is set to: {image_id}")
```

And I've tried doing this:

```
image_id = input("Enter an AMI ID: ")
image_id = image_id.strip()
print(f"The AMI ID is set to: {image_id}")
```

But the result I get is the same. When I intentionally introduce some whitespace in the user input like this:

```
Enter an AMI ID: "  ami-00136e28b857c0ebd"
The AMI ID is set to: "  ami-00136e28b857c0ebd"
```

I get this error back:

```
An error occurred (InvalidAMIID.Malformed) when calling the RunInstances operation: Invalid id: "  ami-00136e28b857c0ebd" (expecting "ami-...")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `InvalidAMIID.Malformed`? Nothing in the code you've shown would produce that error.

Comment: ok thanks let me try that. Also the print statement output is in the OP: `The AMI ID is set to:   ami-00136e28b857c0ebd`

Comment: print `ord(x) for x in image_id` also if you see that removing tab also did not solve your problem.

Comment: !! removing the earlier unhelpful comments. Would like to see the original problem just so the answer makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is ok. I think you are adding quotes ("") to the input string. I mean, instead of write in input `"  ami-00136e28b857c0ebd"`, write `ami-00136e28b857c0ebd`

Try to not add these quotes, or if you need to keep it, clean it with another strip like this:

```
image_id = input("Enter an AMI ID: ")
image_id = image_id.strip('"').strip()
print(f"The AMI ID is set to: {image_id}")
```

Comment: Yes it was the quotes in the input that was causing the problem. My mistake for not including them in the OP that was a copy/paste error.

Comment: Good to know you fixed the problem. @ggorlen you are right, it was speculative.

Comment: Ok will do, thanks.